# how to specify that the Tuple belongs to FSharpCore.dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, f#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Including FSharp.Core in a C# project: resolving type collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136783/including-fsharp-core-in-a-c-sharp-project-resolving-type-collisions)

I have referenced the Microsoft.FSharp.Core.dll file to my web application on .NET.

My fsharp function returns to C# a

```
   Tuple<string,int>
```

It marks in red in C#

```
  Tuple<string,int>
```

saying that it exists in the library FSharp.Core.dll and mscorlib.dll

Is there a way to specify that its a FSharp tuple or vice versa?

Comment: yeah it is. thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using .NET 2.0 (or one the other frameworks build on .NET 2.0 like .NET 3.0 or .NET 3.5) or .NET 4.0?

.NET 2.0 does not include a tuple definition so the version of F# compatible with .NET 2.0 ships with it's own definition for a tuple. In this case you need to reference FSharp.Core.dll and open System and you the Tuple<> class should be in scope.

.NET 4.0 includes a definition of Tuple<> in mscorlib.dll and this is the tuple definition that the version of F# that ships with VS2010 uses, in this case it should not be necessary to reference FSharp.Core.dll. Deleting the reference to FSharp.Core.dll should solve your problem.

Comment: I am using 4.0. I need FSharp.Core.dll for the conversions from FSharpList<T> to IList<T>. Maybe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212%28VS.80%29.aspx could be used but could you tell me how can I alias it in my case?

Comment: sorry the conversion from IList<T> to FSharpList<T>